# Apache Ignite - setting IP and Port on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, port, ignite

Installed Apache Ignite on EC2 and started Ignite node with:

```
bin/ignite.sh examples/config/example-cache.xml
```

That worked fine on EC2 but could not access node from remote host.

Then changed inside exmaple-cache.xml part under:

```
<!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
```

and added ip of that EC2 and then port 80 (which is open for that EC2):

```
<value>x.x.x.x:80</value>
```

Restarted Ignite but was still not accessible from remote host after that.
What is the correct way to enable remote access? Where exactly should be specified IP and Port in order to be accessible from outside of EC2?

Answer (score 1):

If you use TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder, you should add addresses of all nodes, that should be in cluster, for example:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
       <property name="addresses">
           <list>
                   <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                   <value>127.0.0.2:47500..47509</value>
           </list>
       </property>
</bean>
```

But for AWS you also could use TcpDiscoveryS3IpFinder, that was created specially for Amazon S3. Here is a [documentation](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws)

Also, all nodes in cluster should have same configuration for Discovery.

Comment: I just started with Ignite.. Where do I add that bean class? Some configuration file on EC2? And then restart Ignite node? Do I need to have some specific ports open on EC2?

Comment: You should add it to ipFinder property of TcpDiscoverySpi in ignite config file, for example you can see it in your example-cache.xml. Yes, you should restart node after it. 
For Ignite node to be functional you need two ports to be opened - one for discovery and another for communication. Default port for discovery is 47500, for communication it's 47100.  Default range is 100.

Comment: Also, both TcpDiscoverySpi and TcpCommunicationSpi have two configuration properties: setLocalPort() and setLocalPortRange(). In both cases Ignite will use the first available port starting from localPort up until localPort+localPortRange.

Comment: Ignite have a lot of examples, check them at first, they also have config files

Comment: Is there a way to change Default ports? Since it is in company network / VPC and going trough loops for getting approval for these ports will take time. If we can change ports 47500 and 47100 - where are exact places to do that before restarting Ignite?

Comment: Yes, you can change it, use <property name="localPort" value="48500"/>
Check this links for examples
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/network-config

Comment: I added this way - can you check please? http://textuploader.com/d099j
That did not work for me.. It would be great if you could paste solution in a form of whole XML file (e.g. via similar link like above) instead of just one part of it since not familiar with whole XML configuration for Ignite and also it would avoid errors/questions.. I am just looking for working example for port 8080. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read both links? You configured localPort only for TcpCommunicationSpi, but for Discovery toy should configure this parameter too. You need different ports for communication and discovery

Comment: Also, in IpFinder you should add your real ip addreses, so nodes could find each other

Comment: For full xml files check config files in apache ignite, it has examples with localPort configuration

Comment: Tried to search all the files under 'apache-ignite-fabric-2.0.0-bin' but none of the .xml files have example with 'localPort' configuration. It is hard for someone who just started with Ignite to understand all possible XML configurations and where and how to plug them in. Let me try to recap: 1) There should be set localPort under '<property name="communicationSpi">'  and 2) localPort under '<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">'  and 3) Add real IP address. Can you please check updated link with XML:  http://textuploader.com/d096i

Comment: <value>1.2.3.4:80..8080</value> means that range of ports from 80 to 8080 will be used for discovery on this host.
Inside DiscoverySpi in addresses you should add list with all addresses that should be used for discovery in your cluster.
in your case I think it's like <value>1.2.3.4:80</value>
<value>1.2.3.5:80</value>
As you chose 80 as discovery port

Comment: I am looking at docs for S3 setup.

How can I on startup nodes register their IP addresses with Amazon S3 store? Do I need to create file on S3 with IP address of nodes? Is there specific naming convention for file name?